# Combinatorics of projective planes over commutative rings

Tags: co.combinatorics, schemes, projective-geometry, projective-varieties, incidence-geometry

An *axiomatic projective plane* is a point-line incidence structure with the following axioms:

1. any two distinct points are collinear (via a unique line);
2. any two distinct lines meet in a unique point;
3. there exists a 4-gon.

Now consider $P = \mathrm{Proj}(k[x,y,z])$, a projective plane over a commutative ring $k[x,y,z]$ with $k$ a field. Then if we consider the $k$-rational points together with the $k$-rational lines, we obtain an axiomatic projective plane.

Can we also detect an axiomatic projective plane in a general algebro-geometric plane $P = \mathrm{Proj}(A[x,y,z])$, with $A$ a commutative ring, in a natural way ? In other words: does there arise an axiomatic projective plane in some way ?

Comment: I probably don't understand the question, anyway: the set of $k$-rational points in $P$ is the classical projective plane over $k$, hence obviously an axiomatic projective plane.

Comment: @abx: Oops, I messed up mu question. I will re-phrase it.

Comment: What do you mean with a projective plane over an arbitrary commutative ring $A$? If you take the usual approach of considering rank 1 "subspaces" (here: submodules) of $A^3$ as points, and rank 2 "subspaces" as lines (I am being a bit sloppy for brevity), then this yields a projective plane in the axiomatic sense if and only if $A$ is a field: indeed, if $A$ isn't a field, then it admits a proper nontrivial ideal $I$, and you get "points" such as $\{ (x,0,0) : x\in I \}$ which are properly contained in other "points" (here: $\{ (x,0,0) : x\in A\}$, and they are not collinear via a unique line.

Comment: @Max, that comment of yours sounds like an answer to me. It doesn't preclude getting a plane by some other bizarre construction. I'd say chances are low but disapproving the possibility would be hard. So I don't expect we get something significantly more complete than what you offer.

Comment: Have you considered the theory of ternary rings?